# How to read and save barcodes to the DB c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a database called "Employees" and there is a table "EM" So i defined "EID" as my primary key..  I need to read a barcode (employees have ID cards)  and save it to the EID column using my C# application (also I save time,  date... Etc)  .I have no Idea how to do that ..help me please Thanks

(my c# application contains 1 textbox When employee scan his card i need to save his ID number (barcode value) to the data base.

Comment: What you should search is "How to build a CRUD c# application"

Comment: Thanks friend for your help

Comment: A trivial amount of internet searching for "read barcode <your choice of programming language>" will find many examples and discussions.

Comment: I didn't find ant solution yet. I searched for what you said but unfortunately I didn't find what I need

Comment: Most barcode readers when do read a barcode send the translated code as a string. You could have just a textbox and when the pistol read the data the EID would be automatically typed in it. You may want to read about how to create applications that store data in database (CRUD)

Comment: You are right i tried that way but the problem is the are employees more than one so i need to clear the text box How cloud i do that friend any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to build an application or just save data in Database ?

You can just store data manually by bar code scanner

1. Goto EID column
2. keep the cursor
3. Now scan the barcode

Employee ID will populate in the row.

Comment: I need to save it through an application

Comment: "How to build a CRUD c# application

Comment: @user10363184 "I need to save it through an application" You need to store the data a user enters in your application via a barcode reader in a database. The fact that the data came from a barcode is not related to your problem.